# Spring OncePerRequestFilter prevents sending POST requset to a route

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring boot.
I wanna make a login request to get jwt token from server. in the simple way it has no problem but when I confing addFilterBefore method in securityConfiguration class I receive no token from server even if I use antmatchers method.
WebSecurityConfig class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

OncePerRequest class

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private JwtProvider jwtProvider;
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

    if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
        String username = jwtProvider.getUsernameFromJwt(jwt);
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}

private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    String bearerToken = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return bearerToken.substring(7);
    }
    return bearerToken;
}
```

}

Screen shot of Postman when I request login to server but no token gets back.

[image]

Screen shot of postman when  I request login to server but OncePerRequestFilter object (jwtAuthenticationFilter) is not configured in securityc config class. I mean I delete these lines from websecurityconfigureradapter class.
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}

```
http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

[image]

I appreciate everybody who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I had to move

```
filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
```

out of the if block in doFilterInternal of filter class.